# Apple App ID not working in Xcode 9 and Developer Portal

Tags: xcode, xcode9, xcode9.4

[Screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wSJa.png)

[Screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiIgr.png)

[Screenshot #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrj3q.png)

I am trying to create an App ID for my App, Doro. I found out that the error is when I enter in a bundle ID in Xcode, then enter it in the Developer Portal. How would I fix this issue? I never had this issue with my other apps.

I want to use the bundle ID "com.ucode.Doro".

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am having this problem now too.

Comment: I was not, I just worked around it. Sorry.